# Set a range via keywords and format text separately within while not changing anything in the rest of the document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I’m trying the define a range that starts and ends with a string e.g. `range.start` is “text string a” and `range.end` is “text string z” and then applying formatting to strings within this range only.

I can solve this problem with `Select`, but I can’t restrict to an instance as the length or number of times the phrase appears changes. It’s also very slow.

I use `With Selection.Find` with the usual Properties/Methods, but can’t target to a specific part of the document. Only `.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll` or `.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne`

I’d like to be able to target a range and then I can freely execute formatting changes.

`With Range`

Code

`End With`

Comment: Here is Microsoft's page on using the Range object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-range-objects

Comment: Thanks @JohnKorchok, Microsoft isn’t really clear on ranges with strings. They do it on absolute positions or paragraphs. My content changes size depending on the document.

Comment: You would have to do a VBA find to find string 1, get and store the ending character position of the string start in a variable, find the second string, get and store the beginning character position in another variable, then create the range between the two positions and finally do whatever operations to the range that you need to. Searching on phrases like _word vba set range from string_ will get you some sample code.